# Casting collection from one db table to add to another db table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Below is a chunk of my ActionMethod. The part I'm struggling with is casting a new variable **integers** with all **IntegerBufferValues** from **db.IntegerBuffers** and then adding them to **db.IntegerList**.

```
        var integers = new ICollection<Integers>();

        const int COUNT = 1000000;
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int c = 0; c < COUNT; c++)
        {
            integers = db.IntegerBuffers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerBufferValue);
        };
        watch.Stop();

        var integerList = new IntegerList
        {
            Direction = direction,
            Performance = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            Integers = integers
        };

        db.IntegerLists.Add(integerList);
```

**IntegerList**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class IntegerList
    {
        public int IntegerListID { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public long Performance { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Integer> Integers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IntegerBuffer**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class IntegerBuffer
    {
        public int IntegerBufferID { get; set; }
        public int IntegerBufferValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit: To show Integer class.

**Integer**

```
namespace IntegerSorterApp.Models
{
    public class Integer
    {
        public int IntegerID { get; set; }
        public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
        public int IntegerListID { get; set; }

        public virtual IntegerList IntegerList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`integers` is currently a collection of `IntegerBuffer` objects. Use `.Select` to *project* them to just integers:

```
IEnumerable<int> integers;

// ...

integers = db.IntegerBuffers
    .OrderBy(i => i.IntegerBufferValue)
    .Select(i => i.IntegerBufferValue);
```

Or:

```
integers = 
    from buffer in db.IntegerBuffers
    orderby buffer.IntegerBufferValue
    select buffer.IntegerBufferValue;
```

Then, you assign to the collection, you could do something like this:

```
var integerList = new IntegerList
    {
        Direction = direction,
        Performance = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        Integers = integers.ToList()
    };
```

**Update:**

Oops, I didn't see that `Integer` is a class. My answer is to create a list of `Int32` objects. The basics still apply: you'll need to use select to project to whatever structure you need. Now I don't understand your data model, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
// Create your list first so that the list ID is saved
var integerList = new IntegerList
{
    Direction = direction,
    Performance = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
};
db.IntegerLists.Add(integerList);


// Now create your Integer records with the ID of the list
foreach (var buffer in db.IntegerBuffers.OrderBy(b => b.IntegerBufferValue))
{
    db.Integers.Add(new Integer
    {
        IntegerValue = buffer.IntegerBufferValue,
        IntegerListID = integerList.IntegerListID
    });
}
```

If this is a one-to-many relationship, which it appears to be, then setting `IntegerListID` on your `Integer` record will implicitly add it to the `Integers` collection of the list.

Comment: Great answer Jacob, thanks. However, integers.ToList() is returning the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collection.Generic.ICollection<Project.Models.Integer>'.

Comment: I've edited above to show Integer class. Perhaps this is badly named.

Comment: See my update. I assume that the `IntegerListID` property of `Integer` represents a foreign key, and that the `Integers` collection of `IntegerList` is just a navigation property.